# How to automate bitcoin wallet to send return payments to website subscribers?

Tags: wallet, payment, payment-processors, micropayments, automation

When a .onion website sells subscription log-in accounts, they ask for subscription payment and say that a return payment will be received immediately after, containing the payment code for creating a user account.

For example, the subscription might cost `0.001 BTC`, so if the new subscriber pays that, and she receives `0.0002713 BTC` afterwards as a return payment, then the new user can create their account by entering the following fields in the registration form:

- Username
- Password
- Payment Code: `2713`

How can a bitcoin wallet even be programmed to automatically respond to incoming payments with a return payment?

and further, disguise the payment code in the return payment amount such that the form will associate a unique code to each new user (unless maybe they are just fixing the payment code to be identical for all users)

Comment: Why would you want to pay money to send confirmation codes to people? Why not just associate each of your recipient addresses with a particular user account, or make the payment confirmation code the user's transaction ID, or something?

Comment: Ok how can that be done

Comment: Generate an address, then store it in your database as belonging to a user account. Check the address for payment, and when payment is received, mark the account paid. Or, if you want to go the payment code route: generate the address, then when the user submits a transaction ID, check that that transaction ID pays you the correct amount and hasn't been submitted before, then mark the account paid.

Answer (score 0):

> How can a bitcoin wallet even be programmed to automatically respond to incoming payments with a return payment?

What is a bitcoin wallet, exactly? It can be just about anything that is programmed to create keys, check UTXOs and build/sign transactions... A bitcoin wallet can be programmed to do just about anything.

Your question is broad... You need to program it yourself. Build a database to keep track of addresses and payment codes and whatever else then build your site to interact with your database and your wallet, or build your own wallet.

Comment: How can a bitcoin wallet be programmed to respond to incoming payments with its own return payments? never seen that before, given that manual confirmation of payments is the norm. can you link a tutorial? "building a database" myself completely avoids the question about "automation"

Comment: @user610620 You still have to build automation yourself, via maybe setting up a database etc. The process of setting your automation up is not itself automated :)

Comment: Ok how can it be done